# Fast textures ping-pong implementation on WebGL

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, gpgpu, render-to-texture

I'm trying to achieve the GPGPU computations on the WebGL, where I need to store intermediate results. The whole computation doesn't fit in the one fragment shader, so I have to split it into rounds.

I've implemented textures ping-pong technique, where I have two textures, that swap every render.

I have thousands of render rounds to get the result data, in which new data relies to previous (impossible to do them in parallel). I have one big texture to store all data, but computations needs to be on several pixels in each round (8-20 pixels per round, texture is 1024x1024).

My typical fragment shader code is following:

```
void main () {
    vec4 c = gl_FragCoord - 0.5;
    float position = (c.y * TEXTURE_SIZE) + c.x;
    float offset = mod(position, BLOCK_SIZE);
    float block = floor(position / BLOCK_SIZE);

    if ( offset >= (TMP_WORK_OFFSET) && offset < (TMP_WORK_OFFSET + WORKS_PER_ROUND)) {
         //Do the computation here
    } else {
         //Just return the pixel from the texture
         gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextCoord.st);
    }
}
```

Currently, I render whole frame every round, and I want to configure vertices to render only needed pixels for optimizations. The first idea is following:

```
1. Set full frame squad vertecies.
2. Switch to simpleCopy shader program.
3. Copy texture to the framebuffer.
4. Switch to shader program to needed for computations.
5. Set vertices only for needed pixels.
6. Render computations to the framebuffer.
7. Swap textures and go to the #1
```

As you can see, there 5 steps prior the computation itself. I'm afraid, that changing shader program and vertices every round (You remember, I have thousands of short rounds to make the work) will produce the huge overhead.

Another question, will it be faster than just:

```
1. Render whole frame with needed complex shader program (which returns the origin pixel on unused pixels);
2. Swap textures and go to the #2.
```

What other optimizations can I do?